# How to remove disabled if all fields are valid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Use for validation - https://formvalidation.io/

Now, if you enter a full name or username, the disabled attribute of the button is removed

My code - https://jsfiddle.net/dbptqo6k/

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  const demoForm = document.getElementById('demoForm');
  const submitButton = demoForm.querySelector('[type="submit"]');

  FormValidation.formValidation(demoForm, {
    fields: {
      firstName: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The first name is required',
          },
        },
      },
      username: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The username is required',
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 6,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long',
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number and underscore',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
      tachyons: new FormValidation.plugins.Tachyons(),
      submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
      icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
        valid: 'fa fa-check',
        invalid: 'fa fa-times',
        validating: 'fa fa-refresh',
      }),
      fieldStatus: new FormValidation.plugins.FieldStatus({
        onStatusChanged: function(areFieldsValid) {
          if (areFieldsValid) {
            // Enable the submit button
            // so user has a chance to submit the form again
            submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');

            // You can add more CSS classes to the submit button
            submitButton.classList.add('bg-blue');
            submitButton.classList.add('white');
          } else {
            // Disable the submit button
            submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            submitButton.classList.remove('bg-blue');
            submitButton.classList.remove('white');
          }
        },
      }),
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formvalidation.io/vendors/formvalidation/dist/css/formValidation.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://formvalidation.io/vendors/formvalidation/dist/js/FormValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://formvalidation.io/vendors/formvalidation/dist/js/plugins/Tachyons.min.js"></script>


<form id="demoForm" method="POST">
  <div class="cf mb2">
    <div class="fl w-100">
      <div class="fl w-25 pa2">Full name</div>
      <div class="fl w-50">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="input-reset ba b--black-20 pa2 mb2 db w-100" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cf mb2">
    <div class="fl w-100">
      <div class="fl w-25 pa2">Username</div>
      <div class="fl w-50">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="input-reset ba b--black-20 pa2 mb2 db w-100" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cf mb2">
    <div class="fl w-100">
      <div class="fl w-25 pa2"></div>
      <div class="fl w-50">
        <button type="submit" class="ba b--black-20 ph3 pv2 br2" disabled>sign up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The goal is to remove the disabled attribute - only if all fields are valid. If one field is valid - disabled should not be removed

Comment: (Why) did you show us the exact same script block twice?

Comment: I suppose you should simple be using https://formvalidation.io/guide/events/core.form.valid for this?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I'm trying to do this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/ft5vc413/

Comment: Looks like this event only fires, if the submit button was actually clicked. Maybe you need to go via `core.field.valid` then, that appears to trigger as soon as any individual field validates.

Comment: @CBroe alas, but also does not work https://jsfiddle.net/ft5vc413/1/

Comment: You can make it dependent on the valid/invalid state of one field at a time. You would need to "count" the number of fields that are valid, and then enable the submit button when you reached the total amount.

Comment: @CBroe solved with css, this is probably not the best solution, but it works  https://jsfiddle.net/4wzt6cm9/